# Unable to set txpower to 30

Tags: networking, 16.04, wireless

I'm attempting to set the txpower of my Alpha card to 30dBm. I've successfully done it on an old installation with the same card, but currently I'm having no luck.

I followed the guide here: http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/set-your-wi-fi-cards-tx-power-higher-than-30-dbm-0149606/

I had to change the path in the Makefile for `regulatory.db` to `/lib/crda/regulatory.db` as that's where the original is stored. I changed the txpower of `BO` to 30, and ran `make`, `make install` and `make clean`.

I then rebooted.

If I knock my wifi card down, and run `iw reg get` it shows:

```
country BO: DFS-JP
    (2402 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 30), (0 ms), DFS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
```

If I bring the card back up and run `sudo iwconfig wlx00c0ca81fd7a txpower 30`, and then rerun `iw reg get` it shows:

```
country GB: DFS-ETSI
    (2402 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS
    (5490 - 5710 @ 160), (N/A, 27), (0 ms), DFS
    (57000 - 66000 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)
```

I'm not sure what's going on, but any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should edit the regulatory.db to change the setting for GB to 30 and that might not even work if the access point reveals a max TX power allowable

Comment: @Jeremy31That's what I ended up doing. It worked fine after I did that. I tested with 33 and it worked, but dropped it back down to 30 as 33 wasn't needed - and I don't know if my card could handle it.